# How to pump a bag in the fastest way?

Tags: air

I know the airbag utilize the reaction of sodium to make airbag expanded in a short time. Besides this way, is there any way to pump a bag(about tires size) in a short time?

Requirement:
<0.1s, the whole mechanism is portable, can be refilled easily

Comment: Probably, but this is an engineering question and off-topic here.

Comment: The question could also be a chemistry question.  A tightly measured amount of some propellant would do the job.  This is actually what is done with current car air bags.  If you can tolerate a longer inflation time (e.g., several seconds) you can achieve your goal without resorting to a chemical reaction.